# Need help understanding Tomcat vs WepApp classloading issue

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, activemq-classic, classloader

I have 3 webapps running on Tomcat. They all use ActiveMQ. For that reason, i put activemq-all.jar in the Tomcat /lib folder.

With Spring in my webapp i have connectionfactories and listeners. They are created when my webapp boots, but classes they use are loaded from the jars in the lib folder.

The thing i think i see is that any dependency that activemq-classes have, must also reside within the tomcat lib. For example a thing such as xbean-spring.jar, or any Spring classes. Even if i have them in my war lib, i get ClassNotFound.

Why is that? I thought that the classloader for my webapp was a joint set of classes from my war, and classes that reside in the tomcat lib, but it seems that if the class resides in tomcat lib, it cannot "see" the classes in my war lib.

If anybody can help me get my head around this, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat have **several classloaders**, you are putting jar in [Common classloader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions)

> Normally, application classes should NOT be placed here

It can search classes only in itself or parent class loaders, which doesn't include your webapp

> In a Java environment, class loaders are arranged in a parent-child tree. Normally, when a class loader is asked to load a particular class or resource, it delegates the request to a parent class loader first, and then looks in its own repositories only if the parent class loader(s) cannot find the requested class or resource.
>
> ```
>   Bootstrap
>       |
>    System
>       |
>    Common
>    /     \
> Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
> ```

Comment: Yeah, sure. But i thought that applied to every class. In this case, the ActiveMQ class was found in the common classloader, but it seems that any other classes that are used by the activemq class must also be put in the common directory. I would have thought that the next class that the ActiveMQ class needs would be tried in the same fashion.

Comment: @Mathias you can only search classes in your level or above, while webapp is below common